# Find the users who logged in twice in a week

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Company XYZ is storing logging information of users in some log file daily. Print the users who logged in twice in a week.

Example:

```
weekday1.log

weekday2.log

weekday3.log

weekday4.log

weekday5.log

weekday6.log

weekday7.log
```

Each `log` file contains name of users logged in to XYZ site that particular day. Now search from above files the name of users who logged in twice.

This question was asked me in an interview. **And i have a pretty obvious answer of sequential scanning the files as i am not very good at DS and Algo.** Can somebody provide some efficient way to find. Thanks.

Comment: Well, it's not about algorithmics, I think. Since you actually will have to go through ALL the data once, browsing it sequentially is perfect, as long as you just go through all this once. I think they just wanted to see if you knew Java enough to implement it, but they were really not interested in algorithmic complexity.

Comment: This is not a algorithm problem. As I can hardly depict it in word, let me explain it in `SQL`, is that suitable?
    `select id, count(1) times from table where login_date> (current_time-[one-week-time]) group by id having times=2`

Comment: I'd like to know the best (fastest) way to solve this problem, too. If someone has time, of course.

Comment: What's being logged?  What's the format of the log files?

Answer (score 2):

Log is not a standard structure to store a data in it.

Consider if an exception had occurred on the name of the user it may have a chance of printing the user name twice or thrice. In that scenario we cannot get the accurate result. And if some developer prints a log with the user name for his clarification it will spoil the entire thing.

It is advisable that store that stuff in a standard format like SQL or etc., so that it will be easier,faster and accurate to fetch data from it.

If you consider blindly that you need that User Name alone is needed then it will be a ordinary file search.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done like this:

First, store all your user ID and initial login frequency in 2D array, for example:

```
    String [][] user = {{"john","0"}, {"bill","0"}, {"steve","0"},....}; 
    //Of course you didn't do this hardcoded. You may do this using loop
```

Then do something like this:

```
BufferedReader fr;
String usrid="";
int frequency=0;

for(int i=1;i<8;i++){
    try{
        fr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filepath/weekday"+i+".log"));

        String dataRow = fr.readLine();     
        while (dataRow != null){
            usrid = ..... ;//retrieve the userId from the dataRow
            for(int j=0;j<user.length; j++){
                frequency=Integer.parseInt(user[j][1]);
                if(usrid.equalsIgnoreCase(user[j][0])){
                    user[j][1]=String.valueOf(frequency+1);
                }
            }
            dataRow = fr.readLine(); 
        } 
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
}
```

Finally, to print the users who logged in twice in a week:

```
for(int k=0;k<user.length;k++){
    if(user[k][1].equals("2")){
    System.out.println(user[k][0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to do better than linear, however, it's possible to do better than quadratic, which is the naive solution. You could scan the files line-by-line, where you'd create a new map entry for unseen names or increment the number of occurrences for the name in the map. This assumes names are unique. Finally, iterate over the map for entries whose value is 2. This also assumes you mean visited exactly twice in the entire week.

```
public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
  {
    String[] files = { /* Your files */ };
    List<String> lines;
    Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
    Integer occurrences;
    for (String f : files) {
        lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(f), Charset.defaultCharset());
        for (String entry : lines) {
          occurrences = map.get(entry);
          if (occurrences == null)
            map.put(entry, 1);
          else
            map.put(entry, occurrences + 1);
        }
    }
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet())
        if (entry.getValue() == 2)
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " occurred twice.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As we are all well know "Log is not a standard structure to store a data". 
You have to use purely logic to find the login details.
By using error message you have to differentiate both exception and valid login details.
if the credential is valid then increment the count.by this way only it is possible to know..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the files are just a line per log in and that names are unique then I would approach it like by having a Set of names who have visited more than twice and a Map of names with the times visited. Then do this

1. Read name
2. If name is in the set read next name (Goto back to 1)
3. Check if in map - If not add, else check times visited - if 1 increment, if 2 remove from map and add to set
4. Loop 1-3 while more names to read
5. Print names who are in the map who have visited twice.

---

**Assumptions**

- File data looks like this (ie unique names on single lines)

  ```
  David Tennant
  Sarah Jane Smith
  Dalek Sec
  Emilia Pond
  ```
- All files stored in the same directory

---

```
BufferedReader br;
File dir = new File("TheLogDir");
File[] logFiles = dir.listFiles();
int limit = 2;
Set<String> moreThanLimit = new HashSet<String>();
Map<String, Integer> names = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for(File f : logFiles)
{
    // Will need a try/catch here
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    String name;     
    while ((name = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
         if(moreThanLimit.contains(name))
              continue;
         Integer freq = names.get(name);
         if(freq == limit)
         {
             moreThanLimit.add(name);
             names.remove(name)
             continue;
         }
         else if(freq == null)
             freq = 0;
         names.put(name, ++freq);
    }
}

for(Entry<String,Integer> e : names.entrySet())
    if(e.getValue() == limit)
         System.out.println(e.getKey()
```

Answer (score 1):

**My suggestion is the following:**

- Scan the log, create User Objects(with attributes username, timesLoggedIn)
  and add them into a Binary Search Tree.
- For every element that you assert, make sure while you find where should be asserted(by the user of CompareTo) to update the timesLoggedIn if it already exist with +1.
- Lastly, scan the binary search tree and print all the elements that have timesLoggedIn equals to 2.

**Why is this faster ?, because when find_position/or element are applied you simply exclude parts of the tree that you know, are not needed, therefore you dont check there at all. This is evaluated with the compareTo in our case)** So if we want to find the User with the username "johnDoe" in a binary search tree of 1million users, with the first evaluation of the "johndoe" compareTo the username of the root, we will exlude half of the tree, meaning 500.000 elements, so imagine how faster can we arrive at the result needed.

**Note: In order for a binary search tree to work in the best way, it should be balanced, there are algorithms and tools that actually balance binary search trees.**

Comment: why can't we use `HashMap`?

Comment: You can use it, however when you want to update a mapping there or add one, a for loop is used in the put/get method of the hashmap, therefore sometimes you are scanning the whole list again, without excluding any part. However, there are cases that the Big O notation determining the complexity of the hashmap to be 1 (the smallest complexity) but it can go up to n in others. On the other hand, a balanced binary search tree will have an algorithm complexity(big O) of log n always. Overall, with balanced implementations both are good solutions.